# How to listen for html post from website using Python?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

If I have the following html form:

```
<form action="My-Public-IP-Address" method="post">
    Enter Something:<br>
    <input type="text" name="thing"><br><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Of course, replace "My-Public-IP-Address" with my actual public IP address.

Am I even able to use my own public IP like this? and if so, how can I make a listener in Python to listen for the post?

Answer (score -1):

You certainly can't listen with your public ip that easily but its not impossible
Have you ever heard of

> WWW - world wide web

and why people have to buy a website not a public ip

But if you really want to listen to your public ip you just have to configure a webserver on your computer
First, you need to find your IP address. http://whatismyip.com will give that to you (assuming you don't know already).

You can skip this part if you don't want a name rather your "public ip"

> You'll need to point the domain name to that IP address. You can manage DNS entries at the Registrar where you registered the domain name. There are plenty of basic tutorials online for DNS records, but you primary need an "A" record for your domain like example.com and www.example.com.

You'll need to point the domain name to that IP address. You can manage DNS entries at the Registrar where you registered the domain name. There are plenty of basic tutorials online for DNS records, but you primary need an "A" record for your domain like example.com and www.example.com.

Then, configure a web server on your computer. Apache, Nginx, IIS, whatever you prefer.

Finally, if your computer is not hooked up directly to your Internet connection, but instead is plugged into a router, you'll need to configure that router to pass inbound traffic on port 80 to your computer hosting the website. How this is done varies by router.

There will be problems to consider:

> this has so much hassle that you are better off with a domain which you can buy really cheap these days

Your IP address changes
Rarely does anyone get a static IP address these days unless you're paying for business-class service. If your IP rarely changes, then you can probably just update your DNS records when it does. It will take anywhere from 4-24 hours on average to update around the Internet. But your site may be inaccessible for that time period (or traffic might be directed to another subscriber at your old IP address, which is a small-but-real risk if the other subscriber is really knowledgable and really malicious).

You can use a Dynamic DNS service to auto-update your DNS entries whenever your IP changes. I think most of these services have switched to a paid service, and no longer have a free basic usage tier.

Your ISP blocks port 80
Nothing you can do about this one. You could try calling them to remove the block, but you'll have to get past the level 1 "Can you try rebooting to resolve this problem?" drones and the level 2 "We're not allowed to do that" drones first.

Your electric bill gets higher 
Computers use electricity, and staying on 24/7 without power management putting it into sleep mode will use more. Additionally, computers generate heat, which requires more cooling in the summer time. For one computer, this may not be significant enough. But there's a reason that colocation services exist: they are buildings designed for this kind of thing. If you want it online 24/7 and want complete control of your box, you may want to consider inexpensive colocation. I can recommend a really good facility in the Atlanta area if you'd like. Otherwise, I recommend using a really small low-powered Atom box, possibly mini-ITX form factor.

Your server goes down/offline/IP changes right when you need it online the most. 
Them's the breaks. Consumer PCs and Internet connections are not designed for 24x7 server reliability.

Your server is hacked
Let's face it. Servers get hacked, websites get defaced, and computers get compromised, even when managed by professionals. If you run a webserver off your personal computer (yes, the same one that has all those pictures of your naked girlfriend and your tax returns), you're gonna have a bad time.